# Understanding the GHS linker file

Tags: c, embedded

Can anybody teach me how to understand the linker file.It will have different ROM and RAM sections.
My question is on what basis how we will decide the memory sections,its addresses and size.
How .map will generate on this.

Comment: For GHS specific info, Refer GHS Help section II. Using Advanced Tools -> Configuring Linker with Linker Directive files. You need to study this first, then ask you specific question.

Answer (score 1):

The linker directive file is an input to the linking stage of the build.  The linker directive file specifies the type, location and size of memories available to the linker so that the linker can determine where to locate the various code and data portions of the program.  The information that you put in the linker directive file is based upon the design of your hardware and your application.  For example, your microcontroller may have internal SRAM and Flash memories and your board may have external SRAM and Flash memories tied to particular chip selects.  The linker directive file is how you make the linker aware of the location and size of these memories.  Furthermore, for your application you may want particular code or data to be located in a named memory section at a particular address.  For example, you want the startup routine to be located at the reset vector.  The linker directive file is how you specify the name, location, and size of these special sections.  (A pragma statement in the source code can be used to place a routine in a named section.)

The map files is an output of the link stage of the build.  After the linker has located all the code and data sections into the available memories, it produces the map file to detail all those locations.

Typically, toolchain or eval board vendors will provide example linker directive files for common evaluation boards.  And even when you're working with a custom board you can usually tweak the linker directive file provided for a similar evaluation board rather than writing the linker directive file from scratch.